# Guidelines for what should be done in backend vs front end of a mobile app?

Tags: android, optimization, frontend, backend, access-control

I'm developing an android app which communicates with a backend and many times I find myself at the crossroads of deciding whether each decision should be made by the backend or the front end.

I've designed the structure, database management, etc on the backend, this is obvious.  However, when it comes to access control, the lines become a little blurry for me. Take the following as an example:

`Element A requires that User B have permission X to view certain details`

`Element A requires that User B have permission Y to view ALL details`

Now, on the front end I can see the permissions but it's a lot more complicated to handle them than it is in the backend, but just flat out attempting to perform the operation by sending the request to the backend and reacting to its response would be more work for the backend.

In terms of best practice and efficiency, what would one do here?

If anyone has some good resources for best practices when working with a back/front-end and how to distribute the handling of operations, that would be incredibly helpful....thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Security controls had to be made always in the backend to be secure.
If element A requires X to be able to view Y then Y can never never go to the client if it hasn't required permissions.

Then everything will depend somewhat on your application and offline experience you need

Answer (score 0):

Every control should be on backend, as they can be change at any moment. And also if you hardcode those things in client side, firstly you are exposing business logic and on every change over those setting or controls you have to republish the app(in case of mobile app)

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what you're doing.
You can deliver permissions categories in your restful services so that your backend can do the heavy lifting.

The 3 Obvious things you have to keep in mind is:
We don't want the UI to wait for the backend.
We don't want the UI to be slow because of working hard on the main thread.
Secure things should not be exposed in requests.

I prefer to do the heavy lifting in the back end as much as possible and deliver a clean restful api using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). preloading the data when I can and manipulating the ui asynchronously using placeholders.

I hope that answered your question.